# PhoneGap project PhoneGap or Cordova CLI

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap, phonegap-cli

I'm new to PhoneGap, I watched some video about how to add platforms at PhoneGap project.
The most recent video I watched is 3 months old, it shouldn't be outdated and it says to use cordova CLI as also shown in this example.

[Custom Build | PhoneGap Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/custom-build/ios/)

but I also found this page that refer to phonegap CLI

[PhoneGap CLI 3.6.3](https://phonegap.com/blog/2014/11/13/phonegap-cli-3-6-3/)

is

```
phonegap platform add ios
```

an alias of

```
cordova platform add ios
```

I'm really confused, witch should I use?

Comment: So you want to build a cordova app or a phonegap app ultimately?

Comment: a phonegap app I guess

Comment: In that case use the commands that start with `phonegap`.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, Cordova is a library for PhoneGap.
you can add the platform for which you want to develop you app, by adding this in you config.xml file:

If you enter non of those statments, it means that you app is for all platforms.
Hope that help